# How to parse php response as json in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

In php:

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$res = array("success" => true, "status" =>array(),"path" =>array());
echo(json_encode($res));
```

I want to access path from above array.

In jQuery I am trying

```
on("success", function (Text) {
                console.log("l path " + Text[0].path);
            $.each(Text[0].path, function(i,k){
                       console.log(i+"  "+k);
});
```

It is throwing an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined'

Comment: use `response = JSON.parse(Text)`.

Comment: Use `var obj = JSON.parse(Text);` and use `obj` in each. _OR_ use `dataType: 'json',` in `$.ajax` configuration options.

Comment: As mentioned by others, if you want to use the `JSON` you need to parse it first, otherwise it'll be a string.

Comment: `echo(json_encode($res));` are you sure you are getting a valid json out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), like following:

```
on("success", function (Text) {
    var response = JSON.parse(Text);
    console.log("l path " + response.path);
    $.each(response.path, function(i,k){
        console.log(i+"  "+k);
    });
}
```

Comment: Not that I down-voted it, but I can guess it happened because it was answered in the comment of the question.

Comment: I have also commented @Script47 but i can't put complete code in comment. So answer is best way to expose. I don't know why people downvote without reason. Anyway let OP try this solution.

Comment: @Manwal `{"success":true,"status":[],"path":[]}` this is the output of php. so  `response[0].path` should be `response.path`

Comment: LOL, last time I checked this question, there was one down vote to question and +1 to  answer, and this time, -1 to answer and +1 to question. I'm drunk, I suppose :P

Comment: @Manwal It is showing   
Object {success: true, status: Array[1], path: Array[1]}path: Array[1]0: Array[1]0: "http://www.example.com/images/a/post/ee.jpg"length: 1__proto__: Array[0]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]status: Array[1]0: Objectmessage: "ok"success: true__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]success: true__proto__: Object
(index):29 [Array[1]]0: Array[1]0: "http://www.example.com/images/a/post/ee.jpg"length: 1__proto__: Array[0]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
localhost/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: var response = JSON.parse(Text); is showing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
on("success", function (Text) {
var response = JSON.parse(Text);
console.log("l path " + response[0].path);
$.each(response[0].path, function(i,k){
    console.log(i+"  "+k);
});
}
```

Comment: Is this **PHP** Code???? How can you use this code in PHP? This one looking exact replica of my answer and got upvoted. Very Nice.